# Problems with handling a Stack along with a Interface

Tags: c#, class, interface, stack

So im having troubles with my `Console Application`. Im trying to implement a interface with some methods into my class. But i cant really get the hang of it.

- im supposed to `push` letters (`char`) into my Stack with a `push method` from the class.
- I need to `pop` them from the `stack` and write out each `char` from the `stack` into the console. I should also check if the `Stack` is empty with a `isEmpty` method, which I think is correctly done ATM.
- I've also done a `stack` in the `class`, because I'm trying to do something with the `methods`. But it doesn't seem to affect the stack that is created in the program.

The problem I get is that nothing is happening. When I start the application the console pops and runs the code and waits for the `Console.Read()` to happen.

Hope you understand, the code is kind of straight forward. I'll post the `Interface, Class and program code.`

Interface code:

```
public interface IStackInterface
{
    char peek();
    char pop();
    void push(char nytt);
    bool isEmpty();
}
```

Class Code:

```
public class StackClass : IStackInterface
{
    Stack<char> stacken = new Stack<char>();

    public StackClass()
    {

    }
    public bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (stacken.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public char peek()
    {
        return stacken.Peek();
    }

    public char pop()
    {
        return stacken.Pop();

    }

    public void push(char nytt)
    {
        stacken.Push(nytt);
    }
}
```

Program code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                StackClass stacken = new StackClass();

                try
                {
                    stacken.push('t'); stacken.push('s');
                    stacken.push('ä'); stacken.push('b');
                    stacken.push(' ');
                    stacken.push('r'); stacken.push('ä');
                    stacken.push(' '); stacken.push('m');
                    stacken.push('o'); stacken.push('g');
                    stacken.push('a'); stacken.push('L');
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                while (!stacken.isEmpty())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(stacken.pop());
                }
                Console.Read();
        }
```

Best Regards.

Comment: So what is the question? What isn't working?

Comment: What's the error? And why are you just wrapping the framework's `Stack` class?

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: All above, and, I don't see an use of the interface!

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend following .NET naming conventions, laying out your code with one statement per line, and using properties instead of methods where appropriate. Your current `Main` method looks more like Java than idiomatic C#.

Comment: Your `isEmpty` check is backwards.

Comment: @Jamiec That worked. Makes me feel so stupid tho...

Comment: @Jamiec Good catch, missed that. Geez (at myself). @Marcus: Better write `IsEmpty() { return stacken.Count == 0; }`, i.e. return the condition result directly.

Comment: You aren't using [Stack<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for some good reason?

Comment: @Matyas: I'm guessing this is homework. I'm also guessing that the teacher won't be amused by just wrapping the built in `Stack<T>` instead of actually creating a `Stack` class "from scratch".

Comment: Sorry for the flippant comment. It was not meant offensively and was throwaway... until I realised that was the actual problem!

Comment: No really good reason no.

Comment: @MarcusPersson: If nothing else, it illustrates why you *should* use the built in classes like `Stack<T>` instead of rolling your own and potentially making a mistake that you'll waste time trying to find.

Comment: @MattBurland I as the teacher would be amused and give best grades (provided I didn't say "do not use the C# class"). This *is* what one should do in real life. If the interface functions would start with capital letters one should actually just write an almost empty subclass of Stack<char> -- unfortunately we would have to provide an `IsEmpty()`, of all things...

Comment: @PeterSchneider did I understand that right? You would give higher grades for reinventing the wheel? That explains a whole lot about the student-type questions here!

Comment: @Jamiec I'd give best grades for `public class CharStack: Stack<char>, IStackInterface
    {
        public bool IsEmpty() { return Count==0; }}`. This assumes that the interface methods start with capitals, as they should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not do as you expect purely for the reason that your implementation of `isEmpty` is the wrong way round. It should return `true` when the count is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical bug in your code... isEmpty returns the opposite of what you want.  Also, you can optimize it this way:

```
public bool isEmpty()
{
    return (stacken.Count == 0);
}
```

or even:

```
public bool isEmpty()
{
    return stacken == null ? true : (stacken.Count == 0);
}
```

Comment: Ironically, you made exactly the same mistake. Your's will return true if the stack *isn't* empty.

Comment: I'd prefer `stacken == null || stacken.Count == 0`, except that there is no chance stacken is ever null, is there?

Comment: @Peter, yes, in this simplified example, there is no chance of null, but in other more expanded cases there might be.  Besides, it's always good practice.  btw...  I like yours better.

Comment: @Matt, I guess that's what happens when one rushes to get an answer submitted in a race for points.  :-(